# Reading in dates from a textfile/excluding time from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, text-files

I have a text file with each line being a sentence. Each sentence at the end has a date at which it was typed or made. For instance:

> blablablablabla 3/14/2013

When I read the line in from the textfile, I get a an error saying the format exception was unhandled.

```
x.DateOfSentence = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(lineArray[lineArray.Length-1], "M/D/YYYY", null);
```

Where x is the name of the `Sentence` object and `DateOfSentence` is an accessor in a class called `Sentence`.

I have tried regular `DateTime.Parse`, however, that still gives me errors.

Is there a way to exclude the time portion of `DateTime` when I read in the date from the textfile?

Comment: What is the precise value of `lineArray[lineArray.Length-1]`? If it looks anything like `blablablablabla 3/14/2013`, then of course what you have will not work. Parse **Exact**. Not ParseApproximate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the date is at the end of the line, separated from the sentence by a space, you can locate and remove it:

```
int pos = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
if (pos != -1)
{
    line = line.Substring(0, pos);
}
```

That will take everything up to the space, and not take the date.

So what you can do is:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    // do the above
    lines.Add(line);
}

// lines now is a list that contains all of the lines with the dates stripped.
```

Comment: @KarimOumghar: Glad it worked for you. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do some debugging by displaying what is in lineArray[lineArray.Length-1]. That will be the cause of your error as it more than likely is not the date.